# will there be plants and animals in olam haba?

Tags: animals, agriculture, olam-haba-world-to-come

In the future eternal world of Olam Haba (i.e. the final destination following the resurrection of the dead as explained [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/282508/jewish/What-Happens-After-We-Die.htm)) according to the opinions that the body and soul will be reunited, will there still exist plants and animals?

Comment: Why do you think this could be?

Comment: What do you mean by Olam Haba? The space where one's consciousness goes to after death? The Messianic epoch? A later epoch? Something else?

Comment: If your question is premised on those opinions that Olam Haba is physical, you may want to say so to avoid answers taking the other point of view.

Comment: If my dog isn't in olam haba I will be severely disappointed and will file a complaint with management.

Comment: @mevaqesh the future eternal world. final destination

Comment: You have not clarified which of the 4 options I listed you are referring to.

Comment: @mevaqesh by "eternal" I think he has ruled out at least one possibility.

Comment: @mevaqesh the last stop in the train. what is not clear to you?

Comment: Well if you meant one of the options i so conveniently listed I figured you would point to it. Your repeated failure to do so is seemingly deliberately obfuscatory, otherwise I would have little reason to doubt your intent.

Comment: @mevaqesh all those options are temporary stops except olam haba which i wrote in the question. what is not clear?

Comment: The period of Mashiach is a temporary stop? I don't see anything about that in a quick survey of some relevant Rambams. Which sources are you referring to? Perhaps edit them into the question.

Comment: If you mean the current state of affairs for the dead, I doubt they have plants and animals (save for the contents of their graves). Since the body decays anything left would not be physical...

Answer (score 2):

The Leshem writes that any object, including inanimate objects, which were part of bringing about a *kiddush Hashem* or a revelation of Hashem's presence in the world, will exist in the eternal Olam Haba.

According to the Rambam, Olam Haba contains nothing physical. See [Hilchos Teshuva 8:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=5&perek=8&halocha=2):

> העולם הבא--אין בו גוף וגווייה, אלא נפשות הצדיקים בלבד, בלא גוף כמלאכי השרת.  הואיל ואין בו גווייות, אין בו לא אכילה ולא שתייה ולא דבר מכל הדברים שגופות בני האדם צריכין להן בעולם הזה.
>
> In the World to Come there is no body, only the souls of the righteous alone, without bodies, like the angels. Therefore, there is no eating or drinking, or anything that human bodies need in this world.

Similarly the Rambam explains in Yesodei HaTorah 4:1-9 that everything except the soul is made up of component parts and will therefore break down, whereas the soul is [directly] from Hashem and will therefore last forever (the implication being that nothing else will last forever).

Comment: thanks but was asking not according to the rambam. heard some hold there will be a physical body + soul like here.

Comment: @ray Then you should clarify that in your question. And the Leshem should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: do you know where in the Leshem?

Comment: I don't, I only know it second hand.

Comment: obviously not a question according to the Rambam's view. didnt know offhand the source of the other views.i'll search and update the question. thanks

Comment: @ray you could start with the Ramban in shaar hagemul. The Ramchal in several places, daas tevunos for one, is another place to start.